# How to change the scale to an arbitrary number using lightningchart

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

When you use lightningchart to set the scale to be displayed, the default size is 5 or 10 increments.

Is it possible to change this to an arbitrary increments (2 increments, 3 increments, etc.)?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The Axis automatically calculates the increment size depending on the level of zooming for the Axis and space available for each tick label. We're looking towards improving our Axis behavior with the next Major release this Summer.

In the meanwhile, it is possible to create this behavior manually by using customTicks.

```
/*
 * LightningChartJS example that showcases a simple XY line series.
 */
// Import LightningChartJS
const lcjs = require('@arction/lcjs')

// Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
const {
    lightningChart,
    ColorRGBA,
    UIElementBuilders,
    emptyFill,
    emptyLine,
    emptyTick,
    SolidLine,
    SolidFill
} = lcjs
    // Create a XY Chart.
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()
    .setTitle('XY Chart with custom tick interval')

// Get the default X Axis and cache it
const defXAxis = chart.getDefaultAxisX()
// Set the default Axis style as emptyTick, hiding the default Ticks created
// by the AxisTickStrategy
defXAxis.setTickStyle(emptyTick)
// Iterate an arbitrary amount of ticks, creating a new customTick with interval of 2
for ( let i = 10; i <= 90; i += 2 ) {
    // Add a new custom tick to the X Axis
    defXAxis.addCustomTick(
        // Modify the textBox to hide its background and border
        UIElementBuilders.PointableTextBox.addStyler(
            (styler) => {
                styler.setBackground(
                    (bg)=> 
                        bg
                            .setFillStyle(emptyFill)
                            .setStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
            ) }
        ))
        // Set the tick position
        .setValue( i )
        // Make the Grid stroke less visible
        .setGridStrokeStyle(
            new SolidLine( {
                thickness: 1,
                fillStyle: new SolidFill( { color: ColorRGBA(200, 200, 200, 50)})
            })
        )
}
```